# Manage conda envs when switching git branches?

Tags: git, conda

A project has a large number of packages in Conda. There are many branches in the git repo. Some are long-lived, some are software releases, etc. Each branch may have different version requirements for Conda packages. How can I keep my Conda environment sync'ed with git branches?

Some ideas:

1. Make a unique env for each branch. This works but is rather heavy-weight as there will be lots of duplication.
2. Use Conda stacked environments. In my test, it will uninstall packages from the base env. It doesn't act like a union file system.
3. Use docker and trust overlayFS. Haven't tried it, but could work. Some tedious management of so many git branches and docker containers. Like, `git branch -d` should also `docker rm` the container.
4. Create only one env for the project, put that env under git and create branches for each project branch. So project-branch1 would have a corresponding myenv-branch1 under conda/envs/myenv.

Like many people, I currently have one env for the project and then go thru version hell because the environment.yml files don't use pinned dependencies. :-)